# How to make a proper regex match query in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have this code
`String RateBuy7 = Regex.Match(Response, @"</a></td><td>([0-9]+\.+[0-9]+)</td><td>").Groups[1].Value;`
I need to find a number that could be like int ("12") and be like double ("12.5"). How to do it right?
Because that code `([0-9]+\.+[0-9]+)` have only found float numbers. But those numbers aren't always float. Help me please//

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/LJj8o0/1

Answer (score 1):

Normally you want something that does HTML parsing for you, but if you are going to have to use a regex, something like this should work:

`</a></td><td>\d+(\.\d+)?</td><td>`

https://regex101.com/r/aNHbw8/2

You want that first set of numbers, and then optionally a period followed by some numbers.  This should do the trick.

Comment: @Nick192395 if you found the answer useful please accept / upvote it :)  Have a good one!

Comment: Note: `\d` and `[0-9]` are not exactly the same. `\d` will match 0-9 as well as digit characters from other scripts like Arabic.

Comment: @JamesFaix wow, that is good to know!  Learn something new everyday!  thank you for sharing

Answer (score 1):

To match integers as well as "rational numbers" you could use this code:

```
</a></td><td>([0-9]+\.?+[0-9]+)</td><td>
```

Notice the question mark behind the dot. This way the dot is needed zero or once for matching.

I can recommend https://regex101.com for testing.